# is there a way to return a fun that can have more than one arity?

Tags: function, erlang, arity

Erlang functions can share the same name but have different arity. For example:

```
name(X) -> X.
name(X,Y) -> X * Y.
```

I would like to be able to return a fun from a function that behaves in the same way.

In this example I want a way to return fun/1 and fun/2 as one return, so the returned fun can be called in either way, exactly as the function example above.

```
function() ->
    fun(X) -> X end,
    fun(X,Y) -> X * Y end.
```

I could return a tuple {F1, F2} but that's ugly to use.

I could return a fun that takes a list as it's argument, but that's also rather ugly with calls like F([X]) or F([X, Y]).

Answer (score 3):

Here you have 2 different functions with the same name:

```
name(X) -> X.
name(X,Y) -> X * Y.
```

These two functions, as anonymous functions, are: `fun name/1` and `fun name/2` respectively.

If you put any of them in a variable, say… `F1 = fun name/1` or `F2 = fun name/2`, you will not be able to use those vars later *interchangeably*, since `F1(1)` will work, but `F1(1,2)` will fail (and viceversa with `F2`).

If you don't know the # of arguments you'll receive in runtime (let's say you receive a list of arguments of variable length), then you'll need to use [`erlang:apply/2` or `erlang:apply/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#apply-2) to dynamically evaluate the function. In that case, I can offer you 2 ways (depending on the version of `erlang:apply` that you prefer):

**With apply/2:**

```
use_name(Args) ->
  Fun = function(length(Args)),
  erlang:apply(Fun, Args).

function(1) -> fun(X) -> X end;
function(2) -> fun(X, Y) -> X * Y end.
```

**With apply/3:**

```
use_name(Args) ->
  erlang:apply(?MODULE, name, Args).

name(X) -> X.
name(X,Y) -> X * Y.
```

Hope this helps.